# Harvest Not Able to get Project Information based on Project ID

Tags: php, harvest

I am calling the Harvest API using PHP and I want to get the project Information based on the project ID. According to the API Documentation there is a method called getProject($project_id) which calls the project based on the project ID. But it does not display any Information.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
* Register Auto Loader */
spl_autoload_register(array('HarvestAPI', 'autoload'));

$api = new HarvestAPI();
$api->setUser( $user );
$api->setPassword( $password );
$api->setAccount( $account);

$api->setRetryMode( HarvestAPI::RETRY );
$api->setSSL(true);

$result = $api->getProject("6395208");
$data = $result->get( "data" );

echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr><td>Project Name</td>
    <td>Project Creation Date</td>
    <td>Billable</td>
    </tr>";
        foreach($data as $key=>$fruit) {
                        ?>
                     <tr><td><?php echo $fruit->name;?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $fruit->{'created-at'};?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $fruit->{'billable'};?></td></tr>
        <?php ;}
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

But it results in an empty table. Kindly suggest on what can be done.